# Creating a custom shipping rate computation for magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I fairly new to Magento, and I'm trying to make my shipping rate customized. I set my flat rate as disabled, then opted for the table rates option. What I basically want is:

Get the State then Country:

```
If Victoria(Australia) - $5 shipping cost
if everything else - $10 shipping cost
```

Then if item's weight is:

```
 <= 30kg = $5 additional shipping cost (regardless of number of items)
 <= 70kg = $15 additional shipping cost (regardless of number of items)
 >= 71kg = $20 additional cost (regardless of number of items)
```

However I do not know how to set the following options in the table rates tab. What I initially did was to set the condition to

```
condition = "Weight vs. Destination"

Include virtual products in Price Calculation = "Yes"

Calculate Handling Fee = "Fixed"
```

I just realized that I want to add the computations, but I have no idea how. How do I implement my computation for the shipping rates?

I'm using Magento 1.8 by the way.

Comment: What about if you want to add extra shipping cost for each additional item your buyer will choose? How can you do that in the table rates?
Also lets say i want the Expedited Service and FEDEX service to change when the weight changes,how can i set table rates for them too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out.

In the Magento(1.8) Admin, go to the system ->configuration , then set the current configuration scope to main website, then go to the shipping method tab. in the shipping method tab, choose table rates, then set the condition to let's say "Weight vs Destination". Then set after setting additional options(depends on what you need), press the export button to download the csv. You may then modify the excel file based on the variables you need to compute the shipping rate. afterwards just press import to save the table rates to your configuration.

It took me a couple of days, plus I had to do some tinkering in the database(I need to have states if the country selected is Australia, so I had to manually insert them)